# How may I force the gpg signature timestamp to be taken prior to the beginning of signing, not upon completion?

Tags: gnupg

My system for ensuring the integrity of a results file produced by my program:

1. My program does some work appending to `results.txt` which becomes several gigabytes in size.
2. My program appends the current-time timestamp to the file.
3. `results.txt` is closed.
4. My program calls `gpg --sign --detach results.txt` to create a detached signature.  This takes several minutes due to the size of `results.txt`.  The pinentry program pops up and the person executing the program is prompted for their secret key passphrase.

*Time goes by... The results file is archived...*

5. Much later, in addition to verifying the signature to attribute the file's contents to the signatory, I want to be able to check that the signature was made immediately after the file was closed, to provide assurance that the file was not edited between closing and signing.

When I developed this system using gpg 2.0.17 (libgcrypt 1.5.0) on Ubuntu, I learned that the timestamp to go into the signature was essentially that at the time `gpg --sign` was called.  This worked well, as I could rely on less than 1 second ever elapsed between the timestamp being written to the file and the beginning of gpg signing, much too little time for any manual tampering I think.  As part of checking the integrity of the results, I checked that the gpg signature timestamp was less than 1 second after the timestamp written at the end of the file.  That worked great, until...

I ported the system to Windows 7 using gpg 2.0.27 (Gpg4win 2.2.4, libgcrypt 1.6.3), and I noticed that in this environment the timestamp to be included in the gpg signature was actually that at the *end* of gpg signing, or about 2 minutes after the file is closed.  This is a long enough period of time to possibly tamper with the file.

Is there a way to ask gpg2 to take the timestamp prior to the actual signature being calculated?

Answer (score 4):

You can enforce a fixed timestamp being used with the `--fake-system-time` option.

```
--faked-system-time epoch
    This option is only useful for testing; it sets the system time back
    or forth to epoch which is the number of seconds elapsed since the
    year 1970.  Alternatively epoch may be given as a full ISO time string
    (e.g. "20070924T154812").
```

Determine the current time, and pass it to GnuPG when performing the signature operation.

Comment: Thanks Jens, but although `--faked-system-time` is documented in `gpg`'s man page, it doesn't seem to actually be implemented.  [Looks like this is a known issue.](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-gnupg-maint/2014-September/001772.html)  The option doesn't appear after `gpg2 -h` either.  Are you able to use this option?

Comment: I definitely used it once, and I could use it again: although something's fishy here. Using `gpg`, I did not get it running at all, using `gpg2` (GnuPG 2.1 as shipped from the Debian repositories, probably from experimental) I had to additionally use `--debug=0`: `gpg2 --debug=0 --faked-system-time=1442000000 --sign` (which will also echo a warning about using a faked system time).

Comment: gpg2 on Windows 7 (the environment of the original problem) still gives me `gpg: invalid option "--faked-system-time"` even with `--debug=0` or `--debug=10000`.

Comment: Did you use `--faked-system-time=1442000000`? It might well be possible that this option is only available when building GnuPG with some debug flags set, which might not be case with every distribution of the code.

Comment: Update: --faked-system-time still works, at least on macOS, at least with GnuPG 2.2.25, installed via homebrew.